# Good wood for beer pong table

Tags: wood-selection

I'm looking for the best wood recommendations to build a large quantity of beer pong tables in the cheapest way possible.

For those who don't know, [beer pong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_pong) is a party game in which a ping pong ball is thrown from one side of the table to the other trying to place the ball in the opponent's beer cup so that the opponent has to drink the whole cup.

The wood/plywood must be easy to cut, lightweight, cheap and easy to handle with. Any recommendations? I'm going to make 10 first and then more.

Comment: Since you're in Argentina, what is your equivalent of the construction wood sold in North America and much of Europe? This is usually a type of pine or another quite similar softwood up here, I presume it might be radiata pine there.

Answer (score 6):

15/32 (1/2") construction plywood is really cheap at North American big box retailers. The surface is rough and thus makes the game harder. If you're not into challenge, you can get smooth ply for about double.

2x4s can make the base -- a rectangle for the apron; legs screwed inside that rectangle, and then braced (angle, or another rectangle in the middle) for something sturdy-ish.

Comment: All right then. I'm going to make 10 first and the more.

Comment: I will tell you how it goes

Answer (score 2):

> The wood/plywood must be easy to cut, lightweight, cheap and easy to handle with. Any recommendations?

Home center pine plywood and pine boards are probably your best option here.  I used a recycled loft bed frame (made of 2x6s) and pine plywood to make one in college.  You don't say where you're located, but this is based on my experience in the US.

Springtime is coming up, so you can probably find free wood on the side of the road if you pay attention.  Also, if you wait until the end of May or beginning of June, you'll probably be able to find all the free wood you want in your local dorm's dumpster.

Comment: I'm im Argentina. But thanks for the answer